# Ruby calling powershell script - How to deal with standard out/standard error return formatting

Tags: ruby, powershell

Admittedly I am a Ruby rookie. I have the task of calling local Powershell scripts from Ruby code.  I got that working just fine, but I'm not sure how to deal with standard output/standard error.

I can't figure out what format I am getting back, or how to do anything with the output if I do something like:

```
msg = powershell -command c:/temp/test.ps1 #{parameter}
```

The script I am calling is a test script that creates a folder, then a file, then populates the text file with the passed parameter.

When I do a `puts msg` to look at the standard out, I get the following:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         2/26/2015   9:10 AM            temp

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         2/26/2015   9:10 AM          0 test.txt
```

I don't know what format that is in or what I can do with it, if anything to get usable output for the Ruby code to act upon.

Comment: The output is Powershell's somewhat verbose feedback on your commands. What would you like to do with the results?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the output? You can control what you get back from powershell in powershell if you know what output you want specifically.

Comment: Ideally I would just like to be able to parse the feedback into JSON so I can work with it.  At least determine if the script was run successfully or not.

That was my next question, should I control this on the powershell side or try and work with the return data on the Ruby side?

Comment: Here is an example Powershell script I am calling:

`New-Item c:\code\working\temp -type directory -force
New-Item c:\code\working\temp\test.txt -type file -force
$file = "c:\code\working\temp\test.txt"
$lastname | out-file $file`

$lastname is the parameter passed from Ruby.  What would be the best way to return success or error that Ruby can easily deal with?

Comment: Have you tried `ConvertTo-Json`?